# Output first letter of each word of user input

Tags: python

I have this code

```
#Ask for word
w = input("Type in a word to create acronym with spaces between the words:")

#Seperate the words to create acronym
s = w.split(" ")
letter = s[0]

#print answer 
print(s.upper(letter))
```

And I know that I need a for loop to loop over the words to get the first letter of each word but I can't figure out how to do it I tried many different types but I kept getting errors.

Comment: Can you precise what you want to do ? You want the user to type a phrase (be careful,you wrote "a word" in your input string) ? Then the program will create a word with the first letter of every word ?

Comment: phrase word same thing, the program is supposed to make an acronym from the phrases the user inputted for example if the user inputs(Technical media design), then the program would print (TMD)

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It prints a concatenated version of the first letter of each word.

```
w = input("Type in a word to create acronym with spaces between the words:")
print(''.join([e[0] for e in w.split()]).upper())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
w = input("Type a phrase with a space between the words:")
w_up_split = w.upper().split()
acronym = ""

for i in w_up_split:
    acronym += (i[0])
print(acronym)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in w.split(" "):
    first_letter = word[0]
    print(first_letter.upper())
```

Comment: This prints them with newlines

Comment: I need them on the same line

Comment: Use @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 if you need them on the same line. My answer would be useful if you needed to perform more operations on the first letter or word.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you gave you are taking the first word in a list of lists.

```
s = w.split(" ")
letter = s[0]
```

If someone input 'Hi how are you' this s would equal

```
s == ["Hi"]["how"]["are"]["you"]
```

And then letter would equal the first index of s which would be ["Hi"]

You want to go through each word and take each letter

```
acronym = []
for x in s:
    acronym.append(x[0])
```

Would get what you want.